# How to Composition/Association/List of Objects in DAO implementation

Tags: java, prepared-statement, aggregation, dao, composition

A minimum runnable example of my project is above:

`Shopping Cart` and its `Products`;  I need to save this aggregation in pure JDBC, without ORM, in the Database. Is it the proper way to save the product list to DB, passing to the `shopping_cart_fk_id` to each product and its `DAOs`?

**MainClass**

```
package ShoppingCartDAO;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class MainClass {

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        ShoppingCart shoppingCart = new ShoppingCart();
        Integer choice = 0;
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        
        do {    

            choice = 0;
            System.out.print("Choose one option: \n");
            System.out.print("1 - Register New Product \n");
            System.out.print("0 - Exit And Save");
            
            choice = input.nextInt();

                switch (choice)
                {
                case 1:
                    new ShoppingCart().InsertInto(new ProductRegister().RegisterNewProduct());
                    break;              
                default: 
                    System.out.print(" Invalid Option \n");
                    break;
                }   
            } while (choice != 0);
        
        new ShoppingCartDao().add(shoppingCart);
        
        input.close();
        }
}
```

**ConnectionFactory**

```
package ShoppingCartDAO;

import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;

class ShoppingCartDao{


public void add(ShoppingCart shoppingCart)
{
    try
    {       
        PreparedStatement pstmt = ConnectionFactory.getConnection().prepareStatement("Insert into shoppingCart (date) values (?)");
        pstmt.setDate(1, new java.sql.Date(System.currentTimeMillis()));
        pstmt.execute();
        pstmt.close();
    } catch(SQLException e)
    {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }

    ProductDao productDAO = new ProductDao();
    for(Product product : shoppingCart.getProduct()){
        productDAO.add(product);
    }
 }

public Integer getCount()
{
    Integer count;
    try
    {       
        Statement stmt = ConnectionFactory.getConnection().createStatement();
        ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT COUNT(*) AS recordCount FROM shoppingcart");
        rs.next();
        count = rs.getInt(1);

        rs.close();
        stmt.close();

    } catch(SQLException e)
    {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
    return count;
}
}
```

**ShoppingCart Entity**

```
public class ShoppingCart
{
Long id;
Date date;  
ArrayList<Product>products = new ArrayList<Product>();

public ShoppingCart(){
     this.date = new Date();
}
public void InsertInto(Product product){
      products.add(product);
}
public Date getDate(){
      return this.buyDate;
}
public ArrayList<Product>getProduct(){
      return this.products;
}

}
```

**Product Entity**

```
public class Product
{   
String name = new String();
Integer quantity = new Integer();

public void setName(String name){
    this.name = name;
}
public String getName(){
    return this.name;
}
public void setQuantity(Integer quantity){
    this.quantity = quantity;
}
public Integer getQuantity(){
    return this.quantity;
}
}
```

**Shopping Cart DAO**

```
package ShoppingCartDAO;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;

public class ShoppingCart {

Long id;
Date date;  
ArrayList<Product>products = new ArrayList<Product>();

public ShoppingCart(){
     this.date = new Date();
}
public void InsertInto(Product product){
      products.add(product);
}
public Date getDate(){
      return this.date;
}
public ArrayList<Product>getProduct(){
      return this.products;
}
public void addProduct(Product product) {
    products.add(product);
}
}
```

**ProductDAO**

```
package ShoppingCartDAO;

import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.SQLException;

public class ProductDao {

public void add(Product product)
{
try
{                   
    
    String query = "Insert into product (fkShoppingCartId, name, quantity) values (?, ?, ?)";

    PreparedStatement pstmt = ConnectionFactory.getConnection().prepareStatement(query);
        
    
    pstmt.setLong(1, new ShoppingCartDao().getCount() + 1);
    pstmt.setString(2, product.getName());
    pstmt.setInt(3, product.getQuantity());
    pstmt.execute();
    pstmt.close();
}
catch(SQLException e)
{
    throw new RuntimeException(e);
}
}
```

Comment: what do you mean "proper way" ? efficient? extensible? readable?

Comment: @SharonBenAsher Made this by intuition, does not know if is good practice, for example, to call product DAO to save products lists inside de shopping cart DAO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a Java model for your data, what database schema do you need to store it?

It's pretty obvious for the simple types like numbers and strings; for the `List` of products in your `ShoppingCart`, I assume you want to conserve the order of the `Product`s in you `ShoppingCart`. I also assume that a `Product` is in fact an item in a `ShoppingCart` since it has a `quantity` field; so a `Product` has no existence of it's own: it's a part of a `ShoppingCard`.

With these assumptions, I can represent the Java model in the database with two tables:

- SHOPPING_CART(ID, DATE)
- PRODUCT(SHOPPING_CART_ID, POS, NAME, QUANTITY)

and then define class `ShoppingCartPersistence`:

```
public class ShoppingCardPersistence {
    private final Connection connection;
    private final ProductPersistence productPersistence;

    public ShoppingCardPersistence(Connection connection) {
        this.connection = connection;
        this.productPersistence = new ProductPersistence(connection);
    }

    public void create(ShoppingCart cart) throws SQLException {
        try (PreparedStatement stmt = connection.prepareStatement(
                "INSERT INTO SHOPPING_CART(ID, DATE) VALUES(?, ?)")) {
            stmt.setLong(1, cart.getId());
            stmt.setTimestamp(2, new Timestamp(cart.getDate().getTime()));
            stmt.executeUpdate();
        }
        productPersistence.create(cart.getId(), cart.getProducts());
    }

    public ShoppingCart read(long id) throws SQLException {
        ShoppingCart cart;
        try (PreparedStatement stmt = connection.prepareStatement(
                "SELECT DATE FROM SHOPPING_CART WHERE ID=?")) {
            stmt.setLong(1, id);
            ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery();
            if (!rs.next()) {
                return null;
            }
            cart = new ShoppingCart();
            cart.setId(id);
            cart.setDate(new Date(rs.getTimestamp(1).getTime()));
        }
        cart.setProducts(productPersistence.read(cart.getId()));
        return cart;
    }

    public void update(ShoppingCart cart) throws SQLException {
        productPersistence.delete(cart.getId());
        try (PreparedStatement stmt = connection.prepareStatement(
                "UPDATE SHOPPING_CART SET DATE=? WHERE ID=?")) {
            stmt.setLong(2, cart.getId());
            stmt.setTimestamp(1, new Timestamp(cart.getDate().getTime()));
            stmt.executeUpdate();
        }
        productPersistence.create(cart.getId(), cart.getProducts());
    }

    public void delete(ShoppingCart cart) throws SQLException {
        productPersistence.delete(cart.getId());
        try (PreparedStatement stmt = connection.prepareStatement(
                "DELETE SHOPPING_CART WHERE ID=?")) {
        stmt.setLong(1, cart.getId());
        stmt.executeUpdate();
    }
}
```

}

and `ProductPersistence`:

```
public class ProductPersistence {
    private final Connection connection;

    public ProductPersistence(Connection connection) {
        this.connection = connection;
    }

    public void create(long id, List<Product> products) throws SQLException {
        if (!products.isEmpty()) {
            try (PreparedStatement stmt = connection.prepareStatement(
                    "INSERT INTO PRODUCT(SHOPPING_CART_ID, POS, NAME, QUANTITY)"
                    + " VALUES(?,?,?,?)")) {
                for (int i = 0; i < products.size(); ++i) {
                    Product prod = products.get(i);
                    stmt.setLong(1, id);
                    stmt.setInt(2, i);
                    stmt.setString(3, prod.getName());
                    stmt.setInt(4, prod.getQuantity());
                    stmt.addBatch();
                }
                stmt.executeBatch();
            }
        }
    }

    public List<Product> read(long id) throws SQLException {
        try (PreparedStatement stmt = connection.prepareStatement(
                "SELECT POS, NAME, QUANTITY FROM PRODUCT"
                + " WHERE SHOPPING_CART_ID=?"
                + " ORDER BY POS")) {
            List<Product> result = new ArrayList<>();
            stmt.setLong(1, id);
            ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery();
            while (rs.next()) {
                Product prod = new Product();
                prod.setQuantity(rs.getInt(2));
                prod.setName(rs.getString(3));
                result.add(prod);
            }
            return result;
        }
    }

    public void delete(long id) throws SQLException {
        try (PreparedStatement stmt = connection.prepareStatement(
                "DELETE PRODUCT WHERE SHOPPING_CART_ID=?")) {
            stmt.setLong(1, id);
            stmt.executeUpdate();
        }
    }
}
```

You would typically use these classes with a piece of code like this:

```
    try (Connection connection = ConnectionFactory.getConnection()) {
        ShoppingCartPersistence pm
                = new ShoppingCartPersistence(connection);
        
        ShoppingCart cart = pm.read(shoppingCardId);
        
        // do a lot of useful thing with the cart
        
        pm.update(cart);
        connection.commit();
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Note that in your `ConnectionFactory` you should disable autocommit.

The ID of a shopping card has to be assigned before a call to `ShoppingCardPersistence.create` but databases offer mechanisms to automatically generate them, either with an autoincremented column or with a sequence.

Comment: So it's okay from inside, method shoppingCardPersistence.create(ShoppingCart cart) to access productPersistence.create(List<Products> p), right?

Comment: @JamesB In my opinion, it is. Why wouldn't it?

Comment: Maybe it was a bad practice and there is an alternative pattern.

Comment: What makes you think it's bad practice?

Comment: Solid and high cohesion, DAO inside DAO.